# How to pull in Facebook Page posts as blog posts to WordPress?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

After [much struggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709016/how-to-obtain-a-facebook-page-rss-with-the-new-timeline) with getting Facebook to yield it's RSS feed for a page, it seems as though my futility levels have reached their peak.

JSON seems to work absolutely dandy for me and so to this end I am curious as to whether there are any plugins that would import FB JSON as blog posts since it seems that RSS XML's either going away or seriously b0rked.  **Can anyone recommend any plugins to accomplish this?**

Comment: This is an old question, facebook has changed a lot as well as wordpress. And even the stackoverflow-Network: now there is an explicit platform for wordpress questions. Because of this I asked the same question again here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/361648/175043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately after having suspicions confirmed, Facebook has killed this feature.  A solution has been recommended here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9778635/320681

Answer (score 6):

Another way to import facebook post in your blog is to use  http://www.social2blog.com/ but work only with facebook page. Otherwise you can create your own php script:

- get the post in json format  from Facebook ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post ) but first you need to know how get access token.
- for each facebook post insert a relative wordpress post using  *wp_insert_post*

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this: [FeedWordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/).
It syndicates content from feeds that you choose into your WordPress weblog. Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately this uses `Atom/RSS` as you can see in the description.  That is my problem.  I need to utilize JSON to pull in the feeds, otherwise yes, this is what I'm looking for.  If you can find something that does this with JSON instead of Atom/RSS, then you'd be golden.

Comment: @ylluminate did u manage to find any FB to wordpress thing. i m also looking for the same and haven't found anything

Answer (score 1):

I have a non-programming answer to this old question. I'm adding it here in case it helps. OK, I started looking for complicated programming solutions involving SDKs and APIs or even plain old WordPress plugins. But it's frustrating, especially as there's a lot of out of date information out there.

It's really simple. Just use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com). I had to create two recipes, one for normal FB posts and one for FB photo posts. But both worked right away, the FB posts appeared as plain WP posts in my WordPress dashboard, absolutely no problem and surprisingly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Create an app then get proper permission from page admin to read the facebook page feed.Refer this documentation.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Problem with this method is you have to run a cron job and pull the data from Facebook.

Comment: I am the admin and already created an `access_token`... Still no joy.

Comment: did you gave access to the application to read the data from your pages?

Comment: I believe so, can you give a screenshot so that I can verify for you?