# Import Facebook posts and not just embed them

Tags: php, facebook, import

I am looking at importing Facebook posts and not just embedding a Facebook iframe in the page. I want to be able to get the SEO benefits of having my website news page updated all the time by my Facebook page and I believe if I just use the Facebook embed code this wont work to improve it ?. Does anyone know of a tutorial or plugin for importing posts / pics into a php based website ?. 
Thanks
Iain :-)

Answer (score 0):

For this you may want to look at their graph api, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/

you need to authenticate to facebook and retrieve the post using the api

or you can use their plugin to display the fanpage posts on your website, it's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Social2blog ( http://www.social2blog.com/ ) import facebook posts in your blog, with a creation of Wordpress post and then with real SEO benefits. Furthermore Social2blog permit to decide if you want to point the canonical url to Facebook post. The problem with Social2blog is that it works only with facebook page. Otherwise you can create your own php script, please refer to:

[How to pull in Facebook Page posts as blog posts to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714020/how-to-pull-in-facebook-page-posts-as-blog-posts-to-wordpress/38221115)