# Page RSS feed displaying no posts?

Tags: facebook, rss, feed

feed: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=%XX%

Works here: feed: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=146453755423163

That should be the URL structure for Facebook page feeds but I can't seem to get that working for a page in question:

http://graph.facebook.com/lipton

It displays 'no posts' yet I can assure you there are posts.

Could anybody help as to why? Could it be something to do with page settings? The way we post? The amount of likes? Anything that could be hindering the feed from showing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thank you for your response cpilko, just wanted to make clear too we geotarget our posts and apparently that bears affect on the RSS feed but I am yet to find a solution. Anything you guys can come up with from experience would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709016/facebook-killed-public-rss-feeds-how-to-obtain-a-facebook-page-rss-with-the-new), it seems like Facebook is in the process of deprecating RSS feeds for pages. I'm guessing they're doing this like they did FBML: Pages created after a certain date don't have the capability, while earlier ones retain existing capability until it is phased out completely (about a year later.)

It looks like your page was created in early 2012, so it may be past this threshold.

If that's not the case, and you have another page created about this time with a working RSS feed, your best bet is to file a bug report. I've seen transient conditions on some of my pages where API calls just stop working for a week or so, then magically start working again.

Comment: Thank you for your response cpilko, just wanted to make clear too we geotarget our posts and apparently that bears affect on the RSS feed but I am yet to find a solution. Anything you guys can come up with from experience would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can get your posts as a json object using https://graph.facebook.com/lipton/statuses. I could see writing a script on another server that polls or subscribes to realtime updates from this endpoint, parses the data and then publishes it as an RSS feed.

Comment: A great point to consider. Thank you again for your input cpilko!